# How do i get the actual position of vertices in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: arrays, matrix, opengl-es, rotation, vertex

After Applying a rotation or a translation matrix on the vertex array, the vertex buffer is not updated

So how can i get the position of vertices after applying the matrix?

here's the `onDrawFrame()` function

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
PositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(Program,"vPosition");
MatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(Program,"uMVPMatrix");
ColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(Program,"vColor");
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

Matrix.rotateM(RotationMatrix,0,-90f,1,0,0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(vPMatrix,0,projectionMatrix,0,viewMatrix,0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(vPMatrix,0,vPMatrix,0,RotationMatrix,0);

GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixHandle, 1, false, vPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUseProgram(Program);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionHandle,3,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,vertexbuffer);
GLES20.glUniform4fv(ColorHandle,1,color,1);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);

GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU doesn't normally write back transformed results anywhere the application can use them. It's possible in ES 3.0 with transform feedback, BUT it's very expensive.

For touch event "hit" testing, you generally don't want to use the raw geometry. Generally use some simple proxy geometry, which can be transformed in software on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
private float[] modelViewMatrix = new float[16];
...
Matrix.rotateM(RotationMatrix, 0, -90f, 1, 0, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, RotationMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(vpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);
```

You can use the vertex movement calculations in the CPU, and then use the GLU.gluProject() function to convert the coordinates of the vertex of the object in pixels of the screen. This data can be used when working with touch events.

```
private var view: IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 0, widthScreen, heightScreen)
...
GLU.gluProject(modelX, modelY, modelZ, mvMatrix, 0,
              projectionMatrix, 0, view, 0,
              coordinatesWindow, 0)
...
// coordinates in pixels of the screen
val x = coordinatesWindow[0]
val y = coordinatesWindow[1]
```

Comment: indeed this is not my problem. I'm getting the transformations in the screen, but when i try to get the position of a vertex (to use it in touch event), i always get the same position which i first putted in the vertexbuffer. As there were no transformation

Comment: @john sare Sorry. I use duplication of calculations on the CPU, then use function GLU.gluProject() to transform the coordinates of the vertex of an object in the pixels of the screen.

Comment: @john sare Added to the answer, maybe it will be useful to you.